# Spring Webflux Webclient set Connection keepAlive time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Just starting to use Spring Webflux Webclient,Just wanted to know what is the default KeepAlive time for the Http Connection ? Is there a way to increase the keepAlive Time? In our Rest Service we get a request probably every five minutes,The request takes long time to process .It takes time between 500 seconds-- 10 second. However in load test if I send frequent requests the processing time is less than 250ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring WebFlux WebClient is an HTTP client API that wraps actual HTTP libraries - so configuration like connection management, timeouts, etc. are configured at the library level directly and behavior might change depending on the chosen library.

The default library with WebClient is [Reactor Netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/).

Many HTTP clients (and this is the case with Reactor Netty) are maintaining HTTP connections in a connection pool to reuse them. Clients usually acquire a new connection to a remote host, use it to send/receive information and then put it back in the connection pool. This is very useful since sometimes acquiring a new connection can be costly. This seems to be really costly in your case.

HTTP clients leave those unused connections in the pool, but what about keepAlive time?

Most clients leave those connections in the pool as long as possible and test them before acquiring them to see if they're still valid or listen to server events asynchronously to remove them from the pool (I believe Reactor Netty does that). So ultimately, the server is in control and decides when to close connections if they're inactive.

Now your problem description might suggest that connecting to that remote host is very costly, but it could be also the remote host taking a long time to respond to your requests (for example, it might be operating on an empty cache and needs to calculate a lot of things).

Comment: Thanks for your comments Brian, When checked with Remote service they are seeing latency less than 250 ms for one request per 5 minute. I will research more on Connection Pool.